# Problem with microphone key in iOS native app and iOS 17

Tags: keyboard, freeze, ios17

I don't know why it works in native iOS app and it doesn't work in my app. When I have more that one keyboard chosen in iPad Settings and I turn wifi off then the microphone key is greyed out and when I start typing anything the keyboard is so slow and eventually freezes the whole app. This doesn't happen in native app. So I disabled Dictation in iPad Settings and the microphone key is vanished when I type anything in any native iOS app bit it is still visible in my app when I type - the microphone key is still present and greyed out. The only thing that helps is to change keyboard type in code from default to e.g. URL (the one keyboard type which hasn't got a microphone key at all). Does anyone has the same problem? The best part is I don't request any microphone permission in my app as I don't need to use microphone at all. It seems like Apple bug, but it works in native app and I'm not sure if I should add anything to my app to meke it finally work. Any help please? When I turn wifi on the keyboard is responsive again. When I turn wifi off keyboard freezes again.

Switch Dictation off in iPad Settings.